# Getting: Failed resolution of: Lorg/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper; when importing jackson dependencies in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm starting to get crazy with the error I'm getting in Android Studio when importing all jackson dependencies.

This app is working just fine in Eclipse with ADT (is a old app, with old dependencies), but I decided to migrate it because when I'm trying to use Parse, there was some errors I wasn't able to resolve quickly.

Here is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.racsa.oncecincocinco"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    android {
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':library')
    compile project(':facebookSDK')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs')
    // parse
    //compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
    /*
    compile files('libs/augmentrealityframework.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-io-1.3.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-lang3-3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/robospice-1.4.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/robospice-cache-1.4.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/robospice-spring-android-1.4.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/simple-xml-2.7.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/spring-android-core-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar')
    compile files('libs/spring-android-rest-template-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar')
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-4.0.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-media-support-4.0.2.jar')*/
}
```

I know there's no dependencies saying jackson, that's because I have them physically in my /libs folder, but I get java exited with non zero value 2(I have red about this, and its basically because there's a double reference to a library) and I just can't find where and which library is called twice.

Here is my /libs folder:

[image: /libs folder]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this the "hard way" by changing `RoboSpice` and `Jackson` for `Asynctask`. Now the app is faster (don't ask me why, 'cause I don't know) and working perfectly in Android Studio.
In the end, my gradle file looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':library')
    compile project(':facebookSDK')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs')
    // parse
    //compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'

    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.6.0'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.6.0'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.6.0'
}
```

And my `/libs` folder is the same, but without all the jackson dependencies. Thanks anyway!